# Вопрос по области видимости в php

Tags: php, область-видимости

Вот пример кода:

```
<?php

$test = 'nothing';

function check_test(){
    global $test;

    echo 'The test is '.$test.'\n';

}


function run($lala){
    $test = $lala;
    check_test();
}


check_test();

run('Test 2');
run('Test 3');


check_test();
```

Мне нужно чтобы функция при вызове использовала не "самую глобальную" переменную, а ту что уровнем видимости выше. Можно ли как-нибудь достичь такого поведения? Суть в том что в проекте используется pthreads и его полезная нагрузка выполняется в методе run(). Нужно чтобы в каждом методе использовалась "своя" глобальная переменная. Это необходимо чтобы подкорректировать поведение программы и не вносить огромное количество правок в код. Спасибо за ваши советы!

Comment: Многопоточность сама по себе такая штука, что подобных вещей не терпит в принципе.

Comment: @Etki, ситуация такая, что это нужно, чтоб передать параметр функции, которая находится в самом низу. Получается что нужно каждой функции лепить этот ненужный параметр, чтобы он в итоге был использован в самой последней. Я думал это как-то решить по-другому можно.

Comment: Я понял, зачем вам это нужно, но погоду это вообще никак не меняет. Многопоточность крайне нетолерантна к ошибкам проектирования.

Comment: @Etki, ясно, значит через параметр реализую как положено.

Answer (score 2):

Данный вопрос является наглядным примером того, к каким адовым последствиям может привести ипользование global для передачи переменных в функцию.

> Спасибо за ваши советы!

Совет будет такой: **вообще никогда не использовать переменные из чужой области видимости.**

Поэтому функцию check_test() надо переписать вот так:

```
function check_test($test)
{
    echo 'The test is '.$test.'\n';
}
```

и больше никогда, никогда не использовать global вместо аргументов функции.

Comment: В проекте очень много вложенных функций, поэтому в итоге придется добавлять везде лишний параметр, который нужен в итоге только в последней в списке вызовов функции. В питоне том же, насколько я помню, переменная если отсутствует в текущей области видимости, то сначала ищется на уровень выше и так далее.